# Wait for singleton to finish executing before

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am trying to make sure the singleton finishes executing before the UI gets updated. I tried using alertView to show please wait and dismiss it on completion but it did not work. I then tried to use notification centre to update a label in the UI once the adapter changes state.

What is the best way to connect on button click and wait for the the singleton to complete? Should I move _adapter and _transporter inside the dispatch_get_main_queue ?

```
 - (IBAction)connectAdapter:(id)sender {
// connnect to adapter
dispatch_queue_t myQueue = dispatch_queue_create("my queue", NULL);
dispatch_async(myQueue, ^{
    [BLEManager sharedInstance];
    NSLog(@"DID RUN BLE MANAGER");
    _adapter = BLEManager.sharedInstance.adapter;
    _transporter = BLEManager.sharedInstance.transporter;
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        //update your UI
        [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(onAdapterChangedState:) name:AdapterDidUpdateState object:nil];
    });
});
}
```

Update:

If I added in an alert view with a spinner like the code below, would i call it inside the async queue or before i instantiate myQueue

```
UIAlertController *alert = [UIAlertController alertControllerWithTitle:nil
                                                               message:@"Please wait\n\n\n"
                                                        preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyleAlert];

UIActivityIndicatorView *spinner = [[UIActivityIndicatorView alloc] initWithActivityIndicatorStyle:UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleWhiteLarge];
spinner.center = CGPointMake(130.5, 65.5);
spinner.color = [UIColor blackColor];
[spinner startAnimating];
[alert.view addSubview:spinner];
[self presentViewController:alert animated:NO completion:nil];
```

I can then dismiss the alert view inside the get_main_queue using:

```
[alert dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
```

Comment: add a callback in your desired method in the singleton to notify when the method ended

Comment: your code seems just fine. The UI thread will not run until the background thread is completed, ie after the BLEManager is instantiated etc. If you want to "lock" the UI until it is done, you can put up a spinner (HUD) before the background thread is started and then kill it again when the UI thread is activated in your shown code.

Comment: @thomasgotzsche I updated my code with the alertview spinner i tried to implement and then dismiss upon completion. Do you mind taking a look at the updated question